# Weird behavior of EventLog in unit tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-4.5, event-log

I'm trying to unit-test a library which writes to the EventLog. In every test the library checks if the test-source already exists (always using the same source name in these tests) and otherwise creates it.

Now I noticed strange behavior when these tests are running on buid agents:
Lets say we have following test-data:
EventSource: TestSource
ProtocolName: TestName

After the tests have run (and most of the time, except on new agents, many tests fail because the EntryWritten-Event of the EventLog is not fired any more) the suddenly are following two EventProtocols: TestName, TestName2

But I just can`t figure out when and why this second protocol is created.
Does anybody know this behaviour?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could be user permissions problems, common cause for EventLog weirdness.  So on the "good" machines, do these unittests also create the EventLog sources?  It's possible the a previously-created EventLog source doesn't have correct permissions for whatever is running the unittests.  You might as well do the sane thing, and always create/delete these EventLog sources for the test runs.

Comment: Note that since you are accessing an event source (external system) this is more of an integration test, not a Unit Test.

Comment: Thanks for your answers! Is is definetely not a permission issue, because the build agents run under system account. Beside this, I think, if it would be a permission issue, the sources would not even be created. The sources are always created, but after a while it creates a second source with '2' appended to the specified name.

Comment: I already tried to cleanup EventLog in TearDown, but this didn't remove the evtx files (I think until next shutdown). So I first thought that this could cause the problem, but it didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem.

Embarrassingly I missed a test, which creates this protocol. I even could not find it by search.

I also managed to implement an acceptable cleanup method (I had to stop the eventlog service in order to delete evtx files).

Edit:
If anyone has the same problem: Note that stopping the eventlog service also stops schedule (so it must also be manually restarted when restarting eventlog).